# Rails 3.2 - haml vs. erb. Is haml faster? (february 2012)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml, erb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a project and I am still thinking about using HAML (beautiful code, less size of view files) instead of classic ERB template.

My worries why I didn't do it yet are the speed of generating views - I read an articles/benchmarks and there was almost always HAML slower than ERB - but the truth is, that the articles are 2-3 years old.

So my question is, how looks the comparison these two template systems now, in the start of 2012?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some benchmarks from someone in [Nov 2011](http://pastebin.com/G3M7yPrD). You *should* be able to cd to your haml directory and run `rake benchmark`. I say "should" because you'll need to get the proper dependencies installed in order to run that task. I played around with it for a few minutes but no luck locally. The relevant file is `haml/test/benchmark.rb`.

EDIT:
I did find some more information for you. Someone else had the same trouble as me trying to get benchmarks working locally, so they rolled their own. I forked that gist and added support for comparing haml to erb: https://gist.github.com/1807036. I used the same templates that the haml library uses to benchmark. Here are the results that I got running the code:

```
$ ruby benchmark.rb
       user     system      total        real
haml:  0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.651584)
erb:  0.540000   0.000000   0.540000 (  0.534727)
```

I used ruby 1.9.3-p0, haml 3.1.4.

UPDATE 5/2020: @spickermann on github pointed out a flaw in the benchmark, in that the comparison of haml to erb was not fair. The haml engine instance was only instantiated once, whereas the erb instance was instantiated on each of the 1000 benchmark runs. When we fix the benchmark so we instantiate each instance on each benchmark run we get very different results:

```
$ ruby benchmark.rb 
       user     system      total        real
haml:  3.259634   0.007936   3.267570 (  3.271728)
erb:  0.205065   0.000571   0.205636 (  0.205824)
```

This new benchmark uses ruby 2.7.1, haml 5.1.2. The gist has also been updated.

Comment: so whats the conclusion ? haml takes more memory / cpu ?

Comment: Haml is nicer from a dev perspective (in most cases), and if the extra load is minor and won't affect performance at a noticeable level, I say go for it!

Comment: I stumbled upon this old answer, looked at the code of the benchmark and mode some changes to it (see the [comment in the gist](https://gist.github.com/siannopollo/1807036#gistcomment-3305082). I think the situation is way worst. In me version of the benchmark and with current versions of Ruby, ERB and haml ERB performs 20 times better...

Comment: @spickermann I update the benchmark in the answer with ruby 2.6.5 results. What version of ruby and haml are you using?

Comment: @siannopollo I used Ruby 2.7.1 and haml 5.1.2. But my MacBook is about five years old...

Comment: @spickermann I updated the answer (again) using ruby 2.7.1 and hal 5.1.2. I've got a MacBook Pro that's also about 5 years old (2.8GHz Core i7, 16GB memory).

Answer (score 2):

There are already a bunch of debates documented on the web.

But when We have an application where we used ERB exclusively. Why should we try to make the switch to HAML? To me, it's a waste of time and a poor decision that wouldn't provide many benefits. While our code would suddenly be cleaner and a little more beautiful in HAML, we'd waste precious hours converting ERB to HAML. We have so many other important things to do, why waste that time on something so pointless in this case?

It's all relative. You don't need to use HAML instead of ERB. ERB can do all the same things. They are just different tools for the same job.

Comment: conversions of this nature can be automated... see http://html2haml.heroku.com/ and their gem. the point here is a decision of project. If you find that reading tons of haml is better then html, go for it.