# How to improve Sinatra performance using HAML?

Tags: sinatra, haml, erb

I found that when I use HAML in my Sinatra app to render templates it is 10x times slower than ERb.

Is it any solution to improve app performance with HAML rendering?

P.S. I run Sinatra in production environment.

Comment: Where are your benchmarks? Have you profiled your app? How do you know the bottleneck is your HAML gem?

Comment: Related, but not an *exact* duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245854/rails-3-2-haml-vs-erb-is-haml-faster-february-2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether your template creates cached views or not. Haml does cache views so they are basically static. The same goes for sass but you will have to investigate whether erb does the same or not.